# Can "unless" be used in unreal past (with would have)?

Tags: grammar, meaning, conjunctions

I found conflicting information about the subject:
[BBC World Service](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv272.shtml) states that:

> And we cannot use **unless** with **would** to talk about unreal future
> situations:
>
> - *If he didn't take everything so seriously, he would be much easier to
>   work with.*

> - *If he weren't so bad-tempered, I would help him to get the
>   work done.*

> We cannot use **unless** with **would have** to talk about unreal
> situations in the past either:
>
> - *If you hadn't driven so recklessly, you wouldn't have had this
>   accident.*

> - *If you hadn't had that last glass of wine, this would never
>   have happened.*

While Education first [website](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/how-use-unless/) shows usage in all conditionals. What is correct then?

Why I cannot find anything about this usage besides that BBC website?

Comment: Excellent question! But no answers! https://www.englishforums.com/English/UnlessWithReferenceToPast/dgdrw/post.htm#sc2564600

Comment: Not an excellent question: it should give examples of what the OP (or Education First) thinks are correct usages.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another warning against usage of 'unless' for impossible conditions:

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/conditionals-and-wishes/conditionals-other-expressions-unless-should-as-long-as

As for Education First vs BBC, the former is Sweden-based (according to Wikipedia). Not sure if the usage of 'unless' differs in AE though.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty subtle!

---

Are you familiar with the concept of *[presuppositions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presupposition)*? For example, a sentence like "My son is in high school" tacitly assumes that the speaker has a son. This tacit assumption is called a "presupposition".

One major use of the word *if* is in so-called "counterfactual" conditionals, which presuppose that their hypothesis is false. For example, a sentence like "If Alice were here, she would know what to do" tacitly assumes that Alice is not present.

But there's a subtlety here. Sometimes the hypothesis is false, and the speaker knows that the hypothesis is false, but instead of presupposing this, the speaker rhetorically entertains the possibility that it *might* be true, in order to demonstrate that it actually *isn't*. For example, in a sentence like "Bob would have eaten more of his dinner if he'd been very hungry", the speaker doesn't have any direct information about how hungry Bob was, but is arguing that Bob *wasn't* very hungry by saying that if he *had* been, then he would have eaten more of his dinner.

---

Consider a sentence like this one:

> He would be here if he could.

Without context, we can't tell whether it's *presupposing* that its hypothesis ("he can be here") is false, or merely *arguing* that it is.

Here's an example where it *is* presupposing:

> I just got off the phone with Bob. His flight has been canceled, so he won't be able to make it in time. He said he's very sorry. He would be here if he could.

and here's an example where it is *not*:

> I haven't been able to get hold of Bob, but I know that he was really looking forward to this meeting, so I'm sure that there must be a good reason that he's not here. He would be here if he could.

---

So, with that background, I can now answer your question!

- We can use *unless* if we're arguing that something is true by entertaining the possibility that it's false.
- But we can't use *unless* if we're simply presupposing that something is true.

So a sentence like this one:

> He would be here unless he couldn't for some reason.

doesn't have the subtle ambiguity that "He would be here if he could" does.

---

In [the BBC World Service post that you looked at](https://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/youmeus/learnit/learnitv272.shtml), this is what Roger Woodham is getting at with the examples that you quote:

> - If he didn't take everything so seriously, he would be much easier to work with.
> - If he weren't so bad-tempered, I would help him to get the work done.
> - If you hadn't driven so recklessly, you wouldn't have had this accident.
> - If you hadn't had that last glass of wine, this would never have happened.

We can see that these are making presuppositions because of how they use *so* and *that* to refer to specific quantities that are (apparently) already known to both speaker and audience.

In [the Education First page that you looked at](https://www.ef.com/wwen/english-resources/english-grammar/how-use-unless/), all of the example sentences with *unless* are fine, but some of the explanatory text is not. In particular:

1. It says that "*Unless* is used instead of *if...not* in conditional sentences of all types", but that's not really true, because *if* is used in cases where the hypothesis is presupposed to be false, where *unless* is not used that way. (The problem here is that the explanatory text classifies conditional sentences in a simplistic way — only three "types" — which doesn't capture all of the different possible subtleties.)
2. It describes the various sentences with *unless* as being "equivalents" of corresponding sentences with *if*; but many of the sentences with *if* are ambiguous in the same way as "He would be here if he could", which means that the corresponding sentences with *unless* aren't fully equivalent, because they aren't ambiguous in that way.

---

Incidentally, "if" can also be used in cases where the hypothesis is presupposed to be *true*, and "unless" can't be used in *those* cases, either!

For example, if Carol is supposed to be stationed at the entrance to let people in, but then you run into her somewhere else, then you might say "If you're not at the entrance, then who's letting people in?", but you wouldn't say *"Unless you're at the entrance, who's letting people in?"

Answer (score -2):

*Unless X* = *if not X*.

You have to completely flip ALL negative ("nots") and affirmative expressions in X when converting from one to the other.  This can be tricky.

> If he did not take everything so seriously, he would be much easier to work with.

> Unless he took everything so seriously, he would not be much easier to work with.